# How to take Allah as the only helper & protector?

Tags: allah

We are only supposed to take Allah as a helper and a protector, right? How do we do that? Do we rely on Him?

Comment: We should not supposed to take Allah as only helper or protector. Allah can do anything and relying is depend on your faith. and a muslim will and have to rely only on Allah. As there is no god but Allah.

Comment: @ali786 he might have same point as you said. Read his last question.

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/60721/is-allah-the-only-one-protector?noredirect=1#comment98899_60721

Answer (score 3):

I kind of feeling that you aren't Muslim. I thought this because the last question you asked `Do we rely on Him?`makes me think of it.
No problem, you can ask :)

---

So these are the answers to your questions:

### Do we rely on Him?

> قُلۡ هُوَ ٱللَّهُ أَحَدٌ (١) ٱللَّهُ ٱلصَّمَدُ (٢) لَمۡ يَلِدۡ وَلَمۡ يُولَدۡ (٣) وَلَمۡ يَكُن لَّهُ ۥ ڪُفُوًا أَحَدٌ
>
> Say: He is Allah, the One! (1) Allah, the eternally Besought of all! (2) He begetteth not nor was begotten. (3) And there is none comparable unto Him. (4)

This surah says who is Allah and why we only consider him as helper. He is the only one and powerful. Allah can take decisions as he wants and Allah is alone.

This if there are two presidents of one country, What would happen. One would take decision and other would object him. So being along in taking decision makes Allah the only helper we can call for.

### How do we do that?

This is what we have to make our heart accepts Allah. 
**Think**
Why do you respect your Teacher? *because he teaches you and nobody can teachs you better than him.*
 
Why do you respect your Parents? *because nobody can care you more than them*

And if I tell you that teacher is just a source and actually Allah is teaching you by letting you understand, remember, remind, think, etc. And what if I tell you that Allah loves you more than 70 mothers.
I you love Allah as you love them then your heart would call Allah whenever something *good or bad* happens.

Find Allah and win both worlds.

Comment: Nice intentions but he asked how not why. You explained that Allah is only Master and we should consult Him for every matter of ours. OP, in my view, is asking for things to be kept in mind and belief to keep in heart to achieve that.