# Is Allah the only one protector?

Tags: quran, tafseer, allah, malaikah

**YES**

*Do you not know that to Allah belongs the dominion of the heavens and the earth and [that] you have not besides Allah any protector (ولى) or any helper? 2:107*

**NO**

*We [angels] were your allies (أَولِيَآء) in worldly life and [are so] in the Hereafter. And you will have therein whatever your souls desire, and you will have therein whatever you request [or wish] 41:31*

**Plural of وَليّ is أولياء**

أولياء : جمع وَليّ

https://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%d8%a3%d9%8e%d9%88%d9%84%d9%90%d9%8a%d9%8e%d8%a7%d9%93%d8%a1

**The question is - how knowledgeable Muslim explain this**

Is Allah the only one protector and helper - or not?

Comment: i think there is no contradiction, because angels do not have free will, they only do commands of allah.

Comment: https://quran.com/5/55

Comment: Waly وَليّ may have different meanings depending on the context.

Comment: @Medi1Saif By such comments "Waly وَليّ may have different meanings depending on the context." one can defend any text, saying that in it there is no contradictions because different meaning of words are used

Comment: @truthcures in every languages you may, find words which have a different meaning when putt in a different context and this actually applies to Arabic even more. And waly is not necessarily protector. See for example the difference in the meaning in regards of women or government. The only common thing about both is the related responsibility.

Comment: @Medi1Saif do you agree that there is a statement that there is no protector and helper besides Allah?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to ignore any nuance and context regarding the verses of the Quran, you needn't have even gone this far to get a contradiction.

Just take the first verse you mentioned:

> Do you not know that to Allah belongs the dominion of the heavens and the earth and [that] you have not besides Allah any protector or **any helper**? (2:107)

If you wished to ignore nuance, you could say that since my friend helped me in fifth grade by lending me a pencil and thus was a helper, this verse is false. This line of reasoning is, as you might realize, nonsense.

Nuance exists. Speech is not mathematical assertions, and it should not be analyzed that way. This verse does not prevent other people from being protectors or helpers but rather it states that only Allah is the ultimate protector and helper.

Meaning, when Allah decides something for or against you in this world or on Qiyamah, there will be no one to protect or help you against Allah. Other people being helpers or protectors in lesser capacities does not contradict that.

In lieu of your claims about this verse, you could say the same for these two verses:

> Say, "O people, I am only to you a clear warner." (22:49)
>
> Indeed, We have sent you, [O Muhammad], with the truth as **a bringer of good tidings** and a warner, and you will not be asked about the companions of Hellfire. (2:119)

In the first verse, it says Muhammad (SAW) is *only* a warner. In the second, Allah says he is also a bringer of good tidings. Which is it?

I hope you realize how nonsensical this question sounds. That is simply not how language works. When someone says, "I am only a [something]," he isn't denying his ability to be other things. He is simply making a statement in context to emphasize in the moment the [something] aspect of their being.

In the same way, when Allah says "There is no helper other than Me," He isn't denying the ability of other people to be helpers in smaller capacities. Instead, He is emphasizing that He is the *ultimate* helper. Language should be understood in the context and nuance it appears in.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly if would we replace "besides" with "without":

Do you not know that to Allah belongs the dominion of the heavens and the earth and [that] you have not without (the will of) Allah any protector or any helper? (2:107)

?

Comment: @truthcures I am not sure what you mean. I think you should just accept the existence of nuance and that verses should not be taken in the extremely nuance-less sense you are trying to take them.

Answer (score 0):

The contradiction may be resolved if we would understand the word "besides" in the ayah 2:107 as "without"

> Do you not know that to Allah belongs the dominion of the heavens and
>   the earth and [that] you have not without (the wiil or approval of) Allah any
>   protector ((ولى)) or any helper? (2:107) ?

So the angels and other creatures are actually and considerably instruments translating the Allah's help to mankind:

> We [angels] were your allies (أَولِيَآء) in worldly life and [are so]
>   in the Hereafter. And you will have therein whatever your souls
>   desire, and you will have therein whatever you request [or wish] 41:31